# No needing of [seeding]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[1 follower, 248 questions, no wiki description, no synonyms.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seeding)

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**: Not really (too vague) and no (seeding DB tables vs. seeding RNGs).

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**: Yes.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** Not particularly, especially since it's ambiguous.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** No.

Should has fire?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: if the various topics are on topic, should the tag be split?  Such as [tag:rng-seeding] and [tag:db-seeding]?  Seems better than removing it completely.

Comment: Title suggestion: I am just [seeding] my garden

Comment: Title suggestion: Uproot [seeding].

Comment: @Ferrybig: Your title doesn't seem to make sense. It in no way says to remove [seeding].

Comment: Given the discussion of splitting in two, perhaps we should change the title to "Reseeding [seeding]". And perhaps the OP should be ceding his no needing of [seeding]?

Comment: Two years later and this tag is still growing, now 43% more questions.

Answer (score 36):

Much as I love popcorn, please don't burninate the seeds.

Split them into more appropriate tags instead.